# Расширенный цикл for

Tags: java, типы, for

Почему `board` заполняется, если `row` — это переменная, которая только копирует значение элемента `board`?

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
static char[][] board = new char[10][10];

public static void buildEmptyBoard(){

    for(char[] row : board)
        Arrays.fill(row, '*');
}
```

Comment: Переменная row - это одномерный массив. Т.е. в цикле происходит следующее: взять ссылку на строку row, заполнить строку символом '*'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Java [массивы - это объекты](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html), т.е. ссылочные типы. `char[] row` - ссылка на одномерный массив, который ссылается на ячейку в `board`.

Следовательно, меняя `row`, вы меняете элементы в `board`.

Если вам нужна копия массива, используйте `Arrays.copyOf()` или `System.arraycopy()`.